# How to open input fields for editing/inserting data table retrieved from database jsf 2.2?

Tags: java, mysql, jsf, arraylist, datatable

In my app user register and his information inserted into database. If enter  the administration page- you can watch all registered users list. I create method public ArrayList getMeineList() {..} to retrieve this data into h:dataTable - all works OK;  Now I want to have opportunity to update, edit, add, delete records from this list (I think its possible).

I declare boolean variable and add h:inputText to dataTable columns.
Create String methods edit() and addNew(), but they don't work with getMeineList()method, and now haven't no idea how to fix it?!

I try to declare ArrayList outside of getMeineList()method & refer to it, but my retrieved list duplicated many times(although, my goal achieved - fields for adding & editing data open somewhere).                                               Is it possible to refer to ArrayList which is situated in public ArrayList getMeineList() {} method? It's used to set boolean variable to true & open h:inputText fields for editing data!

So, the main question is to which List I must refer to set boolean variable true  & open input fields in dataTable?
 Here's my code:

```
public class Order{

    private int id;
    private String orderNo;
    private String productName;
    private BigDecimal price;
    private int qty;
    private boolean editable;

public Order(){

}
    public Order(int id, String orderNo, String productName, BigDecimal price, int qty) {
        this.id= id;
        this.orderNo = orderNo;
        this.productName = productName;
        this.price = price;
        this.qty = qty;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getOrderNo() {
        return orderNo;
    }

    public void setOrderNo(String orderNo) {
        this.orderNo = orderNo;
    }

    public String getProductName() {
        return productName;
    }

    public void setProductName(String productName) {
        this.productName = productName;
    }

    public BigDecimal getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(BigDecimal price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public int getQty() {
        return qty;
    }

    public void setQty(int qty) {
        this.qty = qty;
    }

    public boolean isEditable() {
        return editable;
    }

    public void setEditable(boolean editable) {
        this.editable = editable;
    }
}

public class orderBean implements Serializable{

     private int id;
     private String orderNo;
     private String productName;
     private BigDecimal price;
     private int qty;

     ResultSet resultSet;
     PreparedStatement prepStatement;
     String SQL;

// public ArrayList<Order> meineList= new ArrayList<Order>();

public ArrayList<Order> getMeineList() {
            try {
                Connection connection= databaseConnection.getConnection();
                SQL= "SELECT * FROM Registration";
                prepStatement= connection.prepareStatement(SQL);
                ArrayList<Order> meineList= new ArrayList<Order>();
                resultSet= prepStatement.executeQuery();
                 boolean foundResult= false;
                 while (resultSet.next()== true) {
                    Order orderBean= new Order(id, orderNo, productName, price, qty);
                    orderBean.setId(resultSet.getInt("id"));
                    orderBean.setOrderNo(resultSet.getString("orderNo"));
                    orderBean.setProductName(resultSet.getString("productName"));
                    orderBean.setPrice(resultSet.getBigDecimal("price"));
                    orderBean.setQty(resultSet.getInt("qty"));
                    meineList.add(orderBean);
                    foundResult= true;
                }
                resultSet.close();
                prepStatement.close();
                if (foundResult) {
                    return meineList;
                } else {
                    return null; //no entries found.
                }
            } catch (Exception eX) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                System.out.println("Error in getMeineList()--> "+eX.getMessage());
                return (null);
            }
        }
    public String edit(Order bean){
        bean.setEditable(true);
        return "";
    }

    public String addNew(){
         Order newUser= new Order();
         newUser.setEditable(true);
         meineList.add(newUser);
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! 17 views, but no replies still, something wrong with my question?!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Not everyone will want to answer or may even have an answer, so **you need to be patient**. A much better gauge for quality is your post's **score**.

Comment: And if you target your question to broadly. Like here: it is not java-se related (can you reproduce with an java class with a main and only imports from the jdk?). Is it mysql related? Most likely not (it would fail with postgress to or M$SQL), Can you populate the datatable from a static list? If so, it is is not jsf related. With to broadly tagged questions, you'll get views from people that are interested in tags to which your question is not related. Consequence: lots of views but no answers. So narrow your problem down. See [mcve]